# import beanstalk (pybeanstalk) results "import error no module named 'serverconn'"

Tags: python, beanstalkd

I am running Spyder with Anaconda 2.4.1 (64 bit) and Python 3.5.1 on Win 10. When I attempt to import pybeanstalk via:

`import beanstalk`

The IPython console returns:

`import error no module named 'serverconn'`

I've done my googling of the error and all I ever get is a Google Groups thread where someone is having an issue with pyyaml not being installed. The thread is about pybeanstalk so I expect it is related. However, it doesn't offer any solutions. The rest of the results aren't any better. However, pyyaml was installed. It is now updated as well. Problem remains.

I have attempted to google the exact error but nothing is found so Google returns broad match results instead of exact match results. The result is a string of results about various other packages not being found.

The only reference to serverconn I can find on Google is serverconn.py as part of the Google Groups thread mentioned previously.

I have also attempted to install from here https://github.com/beanstalkd/pybeanstalk with the same result.

I noticed that some of the beanstalk packages were compatible with Python 3. pybeanstalk did not mention that though.

What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: Exact same issue here on Windows with Python 3.5.1. I created an issue on the pybeanstalk repository [here](https://github.com/beanstalkd/pybeanstalk/issues/25).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After submiting [this issue](https://github.com/beanstalkd/pybeanstalk/issues/25) on the official repository of pybeanstalk, here is the [response](https://github.com/beanstalkd/pybeanstalk/issues/25#issuecomment-230829472) from one of the maintainers:

> Python 3 is not supported. Feel free to open an issue for that. No guarantees that anyone will have time to work on that though. Updating this package to support Python3 is not trivial.

**Edit:** I found a Python 3 only version of a Beanstalkd client [here](https://github.com/menezes-/pystalkd), named pystalkd.

Another, named [pystalk](https://github.com/EasyPost/pystalk), is compatible for both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Not sure if it's standard practice, but might be nice if the library did a quick `import sys` to check and bail if `sys.version_info.major == 3` - perhaps add that in as a request as well? Then the error could be hand-crafted to say `pybeanstalk does not (currently) support python3. Click <here> to fork our github and help us!` or some such helpful response?

Comment: Thanks for the information @Epoc. I had begun to suspect a version issue but I was hopeful it was a simple matter to fix. I did a lot of searching for alternative packages but never found pystalkd. So... I must have done my searching wrong. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @gabe Me too, for some reason pystalkd isn't easly findable :) You're welcome !